# Biblioteca de sessão para NodeJS/HapiJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, login, vue.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de email e cheguei na parte onde preciso fazer a parte de sessão e login, porém nunca fiz isso antes, estou usando o HapiJS como servidor e gostaria de saber quais as melhores bibliotecas de sessão, e também quais outros recursos que eu vou precisar. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Front-end: VueJS/Quasar

Servidor: HapiJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) é uma boa opção para login e ele está disponível para [hapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-passport). Com express verifico se o usuário está logado na interceptação com express-session. Não tenho propriedade para falar sobre o hapi, mas pesquisando vi que existe o [hapi-sesion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-session).

### Exemplo

*autenticador.js*

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.usuario) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  return next();
};
```

*rota.js*

```
var autenticar = require('autenticador');
router.get('/index', autenticar , function(req, res){

    res.status(200).json({
        mensagem: 'Logado!'
    });
});
```

Esse é um exemplo com express e node, onde o usuário é salvo na sessão no *callback* de sucesso do login e usado nas rotas. Provável que precise adaptar um pouco para o hapi ou surja alguém com esse conhecimento aqui :)

Comment: Vou adaptar para o Hapi, também não sei muito sobre ele, mas estou aprendendo. e com essa parte da sessão implementada vai adiantar bastante o que estou fazendo. Muito obrigado por me ajudar mais uma vez.